# How to hide the output message of the curl elasticsearch command?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

Can not I get the message out of curl elasticsearch command?

ex)

```
> /usr/bin/curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@/home/1003783/data/20161201.json"
=> {"took":9,"errors":false,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"ctlg_info","_type":"1002154","_id":"20161201","_version":2,"_shards":{"total":3,"successful":3,"failed":0},"status":200}}]}
```

When I run the curl command against elasticsearch, I do not want to see the above message. It seems to be a message from elasticsearch.

Thank you.

Comment: you don't want to see the response ?

Comment: I do not want to see the above message.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-o` switch and send the output to `dev/null`

```
> /usr/bin/curl -s -o /dev/null -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@/home/1003783/data/20161201.json"
```